# WordPress: how to change URL for individual MultiSites?

Tags: multisite, redirect, htaccess, site-url

Currently we have a MultiSite setup for our main website, and the URL's appear as follows:

`http://sub.domain.com/site-a` (Site A)

`http://sub.domain.com/site-b` (Site B)

Site A is OK as is. But we would like Site B to have the URL `http://site-b.domain.com`. Additionally, all content of Site B should appear as follows: `http://site-b.domain.com/page-1`, etc.

We currently use `http://site-b.domain.com`, but once we have the Site B (multisite) ready to launch, we would like to replace this existing site.

I am curious to the suggestions and solutions, as this almost seems impossible to me.